# Piping transformed read stream into request.post()

Tags: node.js

I'd like parse a log file and POST what is read to a request endpoint. I've managed to build a solution that generates a request for every log line read. However, it doesn't create any back pressure so it just flogs the server and I'd like to slow it down.

This lead me to investigate using stream pipes to see if I could route data from a file directly into request.post(). I can't get the post call to post a body object though.

```
var stream = require('stream');
var request = require('request');
var liner = new stream.Transform( { objectMode: true } );

liner._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
     var data = chunk.toString()
     if (this._lastLineData) data = this._lastLineData + data 

     var lines = data.split('\n') 
     this._lastLineData = lines.splice(lines.length-1,1)[0] 

     var that = this;
     lines.forEach(function(line) {
        var line_obj = JSON.parse(line);
        if( line_obj.url === "/api/usages" && line_obj.method === 'POST' ) {
            var req_body = line_obj.body.body;
            that.push.bind(req_body);
        }
     });
     done();
}

var file_name = process.argv[2];
console.log('Reading from ' + file_name);

var fs = require('fs')
var liner = require('./liner')
var source = fs.createReadStream(file_name)
source.pipe(liner).pipe(request
                            .post("http://localhost:8081/api/usages")
                            .on('response', function(response) {
                                console.log(response.statusCode) // 200
                            })
                            .on('error', function(err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            }));
```

The push call in the transform function is working correctly, but it's not posting that object via the body in request.post().

What am I missing?

Will this provide the back pressure I'm looking for to throttle the POST calls before all of the file reads are completed?

Comment: any luck with a solution. I'm also wanting to pipe a transform stream to a request

Comment: i used a queue to solve the back pressure but never found a solution to the original streaming question. i'll post my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I wasn't able to find a solution to the ***streaming*** question, I found a simple solution to the back pressure question.

I used async.queue to push work into a simple task queue.

```
// build the send queue
var pool = new http.Agent({keepAlive: true, keepAliveMsecs: 10000, maxSockets: Math.floor(send_queue_concurrency*1.5)});
var q = async.queue(function(task, callback){
    request({
        url    : 'http://localhost:8081/xxxxxx',
        method : 'POST',
        json   : task.req_body,
        gzip   : true,
        pool   : pool,
        timeout: 30000
    }, function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
            console.log('request error : ' + error);
            post_status.fail++;
        } else {
            if( response.statusCode === 400 ) {
                console.dir(body);
            }
        }
        callback();
    });

}, send_queue_concurrency);
q.drain = done;
```

`send_queue_concurrency` is the primary lever for controlling request pressure.

i'm pushing work into the queue with a file parsing routine :

```
rl.on('line', function(line) {
    line_count++;
    try {
        var line_object = JSON.parse(line);
        var req_body = line_object.body.body;
        q.push({req_body:req_body, line_object:line_object}, function(err){
            if (err){
                console.log('queue error! '+JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        });
    } catch( e ) {
        console.dir(e);
    }
});

var done = function() {
    // print out some reporting stats...
    // console.log('xxxxxx');
    console.log('\ndone.');
    process.exit(0);    
};
```

Comment: I think your solution is the best we can do... particularly when there is no ability to multipart/upload to the server

Answer (score 3):

I've discovered that you cannot pipe a stream to an HTTP request because you would need the Content-Length known before hand (as per spec). The less pleasant alternative is to multipart the upload - as chunks are read from your transform they would marshal parts to the receiving API. This also means the receiving API needs to be able to receive multipart uploads and reassemble the whole file after all parts have been received and confirmed. AWS S3 has multipart uploads and it might be a nice example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html

I wanted to pipe my transform data to another API that I manage but it seems the effort is not likely worth it considering my files really aren't that big. I'll update this answer if I change my mind :)